# adding values in a 2d associative array

Tags: php, arrays

The following code returns an associated array with a url,title and snippet from a search engine and it works fine

```
$js = json_decode($data); 

    $blekkoArray = array();                     

    $find = array ('http://','https://','www.');

    foreach ($js->RESULT as $item)
    {   
        $blekkoArray[$i]['url'] = str_replace ($find, '', ($item->{'url'}) );         
        $blekkoArray[$i]['title'] = ($item->{'url_title'});
        $blekkoArray[$i]['snippet'] = ($item->{'snippet'});
        $i++;
    }

    print_r ($blekkoArray);
```

I'm trying to add another value to the array so that I can score each element, eg. I want the first result to have a score of 100, the second 99, the third 98 and so on, the following code spits out the same as the above. Therefore I can't seem to add 'score' the the array, any thoughts.
Reagrds

```
$js = json_decode($data); 

    $blekkoArray = array();                     

    $find = array ('http://','https://','www.');

    foreach ($js->RESULT as $item)
    {   
        $score = 100;
        $blekkoArray[$i]['url'] = str_replace ($find, '', ($item->{'url'}) );         
        $blekkoArray[$i]['title'] = ($item->{'url_title'});
        $blekkoArray[$i]['snippet'] = ($item->{'snippet'});
        $blekkoArray[$i]['score'];
        $i++;
        $score--;
    }

    print_r ($blekkoArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done 2 mistakes.

1) you have initialized `$score` inside foreach loop, it should be outside otherwise you will get $score = 100 always.

2) You are not assigning the $score in array,

```
$score = 100; // move the initialization of $score outside of loop
foreach ($js->RESULT as $item)
{           
    $blekkoArray[$i]['url'] = str_replace ($find, '', ($item->{'url'}) );         
    $blekkoArray[$i]['title'] = ($item->{'url_title'});
    $blekkoArray[$i]['snippet'] = ($item->{'snippet'});
    $blekkoArray[$i]['score'] = $score;      // assign the $score value here
    $i++;
    $score--;
}
```

**OR** suggested by **u_mulder**

```
$blekkoArray[$i]['score'] = $score--;
```

Comment: even `$blekkoArray[$i]['score'] = $score--;` and remove the `$score--;`)

Comment: Nope. first it assigns, then reduce) But `--$score` reduces and then assigns.

Comment: Yups, that's what I did first: Pre-decrement in stead of post-decrement x) But indeed, $score-- first assigns $score to the left side variable, then decrements it by one.

Comment: Yep thanks guys, I'm still trying to get to grips with foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

Bring the `$score = 100;` outside of the foreach array. You're resetting it to 100 each loop.
And use

```
$blekkoArray[$i]['score'] = $score--;
```

or the same on two lines:

```
$blekkoArray[$i]['score'] = $score;
$score--;
```

And next to that, can't you use the **key** in the foreach? Like this? This is just a guess, as I don't know what `$i` is. It's not defined or initialised in your code, so...
And a little bonus modification: if you're not using variables as fieldnames, the `$var->{'fieldname'}` notation can be simplified to `$var->fieldname`.

All together, this is giving the following code:

```
$score = 100;
foreach ($js->RESULT as $i => $item)
{
    $blekkoArray[$i]['url'] = str_replace ($find, '', $item->url);
    $blekkoArray[$i]['title'] = $item->url_title;
    $blekkoArray[$i]['snippet'] = $item->snippet;
    $blekkoArray[$i]['score'] = $score--;
}
```

Comment: --$score will set first value as 99

Comment: Right @Pamil :) That's my bad. Thanks for the feedback ;)